# AngularJS - Cross Orgin Requests error

Tags: angularjs

Try to read a local file. Get the following error. I've tried all the Angular CORS tricks. But no luck any ideas what I'm doing wrong. Should work

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C://www/mapping.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

```
var App = angular.module('Search', ['ngResource', 'ionic'])
         .config(function ($httpProvider) {
             $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
             delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
         });


  var x = $http.get('mapping.json');
```

Comment: Why don't you use a local server? For example Node.js

Comment: Unless you're submitting a large amount of data (over 500 bytes) you should stick with using JSONP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS required server side header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin

not sure how that works with plain files,

please see for more info: http://enable-cors.org/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a file permission error and you don't have the rights to read the file. Try changing the permissions of that folder